# Pyspark kafka readStream

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm reading data from kafka topic using the below code.

```
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.3,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.3 pyspark-shell'

df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.server", kafkaServer).option("subscribe", topic_name_read).option("includeHeaders", "true").option("startingOffsets", "earliest").load()
```

But it throws the below error.

`File "C:\spark\spark-3.1.3-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 210, in loadreturn self._df(self._jreader.load())File "C:\spark\spark-3.1.3-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1304, in callFile "C:\spark\spark-3.1.3-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 111, in decoreturn f(*a, **kw)File "C:\spark\spark-3.1.3-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_valuepy4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o37.load.: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/ByteArraySerializerat org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.<init>(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:556)at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.<clinit>(KafkaSourceProvider.scala)at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.org$apache$spark$sql$kafka010$KafkaSourceProvider$$validateBatchOptions(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:336)at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.createRelation(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:127)at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:355)at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:325)at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:307)at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:307)at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:225)at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializerat java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)... 21 more`

If I use only .load instead on load(), It unable to identify withColumn function.

```
df1 = df.withColumn("items", F.explode(F.col("items")))
```

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'withColumn'

Thank you

**Environment:**

Python - 3.9.9

pySpark - 3.1.3

kafka-python - 2.0.2

spark-hadoop - 3.1.3 and 2.7

**Jar Used**

spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.3,

spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.3

Comment: Spark doesn't need `kafka-python` dependency, by the way

Answer (score 0):

`.load()` is correct.

Your real error:

> `ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer`

You need to include `kafka-clients` dependency in your `--packages` arg

Also, you are only using `spark-sql-kafka` here, so you should remove the other one.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've posted another question, to display the data frame on the console. I've error regarding, `pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start(); kafka`

Comment: You've not shown your full code. In the output of the dataframe, you need to use those functions listed in the error. Example - https://github.com/sparkbyexamples/spark-examples/blob/master/spark-streaming/src/main/scala/com/sparkbyexamples/spark/streaming/kafka/json/SparkStreamingConsumerKafkaJson.scala#L62